# How to use DISTINCT and SUM in a same SQL query on MS SQL Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have a situation where I need to get DISTINCT values from column "note" and then get the SUM of "price" for above records.

I tried with different queries but none of them are working fine.

```
SELECT    DISTINCT   note ,price( select SUM (price) FROM  [tableName] where Archived ='0'

SELECT    sum(price),(SELECT DISTINCT  note , price from  [tableName] where Archived ='0')
```

In a nutshell I need to get the sum of prices for the distinct records.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What is your database ?

Comment: I have attached a SS

Comment: Not of much use for us, this is a image of the data please add text. Also add a small amount of data that represents your problem, not all bunch of them...We do not know what is your expected result and what database do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxbe this will be one way to do it:

```
select distinct sum(price) over(partition by note), note
from tablename
where Archived = 0
```

[Here is a demo on SQLServer](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31fb846b9bdcb43cd71d684043580092)

If I have understood you correctly you need distinct note values and only one sum for all of them ... then something like this:

```
select distinct note, (select sum(price) from tablename) sum_tot
from tablename
where Archived = 0
```

P.S. do add expected result....

Comment: mmm..not at all. Coz im looking for a final out put as "sum" . Just a one singale output.

Comment: Show us the example of the result for the data you have added in your question. If it is one sum, where is the distinct part of the story ?

Comment: Hi @user2728409 I have updated my answer... Maybe this is what you need ?

Comment: I use distict ,becouse table contain duplicate records ,Only the Note field is so uniqe.

Comment: YES, this looks soooo good.Thanks mate.I got multiple records with note field and the actual sum for all other.So i can symply get the top most record and thats it.Thanks

Comment: @user2728409: The top most row??? So this is yet something else you want. Are you simply looking for the note with the highest price sum? You should really update your request and show sample data to illustrate the result you are actually after.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for `group by`?

```
SELECT note, SUM(price)
FROM [tableName] 
WHERE Archived = '0'
GROUP BY note;
```

If you want the sum over ALL the records, just use window functions like this:

```
SELECT note, SUM(price) as note_sum, SUM(SUM(price)) OVER () as total_sum
FROM [tableName] 
WHERE Archived = '0'
GROUP BY note;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce ,But this is not what im looking for.I just need the sum of the uniqe recods on the table.

Comment: @user2728409 . . . You have asked for:  "I have a situation where I need to get DISTINCT values from coulmmn name "note" and then get the SUM of "price" for above recordes."  That is what this query does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have understood OP because of some comments and I do agree with you it was a not so good description.  OP wants one sum of all price values regardless to any column value, and all different records based on note column...One vote up from me too...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff mmmm... may be I did not express my question corectly.But at the end i said "In a nutshell I need to get the sum of prices for the distinct records.
"

Comment: @user2728409: Does "distinct records" mean you have **exact duplicates in the table** you want to ignore when adding up prices? If so, you may just want to clean up your table (and introduce a constraint so as not to have duplicates in the future.)

Comment: @user2728409 . . . That still sounds (to me at least) more like "the sum of prices for each distinct record [note]" rather than the "the total sum of all records in the table".  People use language in different ways, so it is not uncommon for something obvious to one person to not be obvious to another.

Comment: Hi  @Thorsten Kettner you may just want to clean up.Thats what im looking at rite now.A better way to remove duplicates.Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user2728409: There are many requests here on SO how to do this. It's mainly "delete from the table where another row with the same data exists": `delete from mytable where exists (select null from mytable other where other.id < mytable.id and other.col1 = mytable.col1 and other.col2 = mytable.col2 ...);`.